# Text classifier to predict gender from Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, text-classification

I am trying to build a text classifier to predict the gender of twitter users based on their tweets.   It is my first time building a text classification model and I am not sure of my steps.

**Two Dataframes**

I have a data frame that acts as the training dataset. It contains each user ID and their gender.

```
train_lables=({'id':['33324','24442','3956'],
     'gender':['female','male','male']})
train_lables=pd.DataFrame(train_lables)
```

I also have a dataset that acts as the training and testing dataset. It contains the tweets of the users.

```
tweets=({'id':['33324','24442','3956'],
         'tweets':[['hello','trump','today'],['blue','eyes','brown','hair'],['playstation','june']]})
tweets=pd.DataFrame(tweets)
```

**tuples?**

I want to perform features extraction to train my model. So far I have created tuples using each row from each data frame as below.

```
#gender for each user id 
training_labels_tuple=[tuple(x) for x in training_labels.to_records(index=False)]
```

The output is

```
[('33324', 'female'), ('24442', 'male'), ('3956', 'male')]
```

As well as a tuple of user id and tweets

```
tweets_tuple=[tuple(x) for x in tweets.to_records(index=False)]
```

the output is

```
[('33324', ['hello', 'trump', 'today']),
 ('24442', ['blue', 'eyes', 'brown', 'hair']),
 ('3956', ['playstation', 'june'])]
```

I am not sure if I should merge the tweets and gender into one tuple and use that to train my model.

Could someone please guide me through the correct steps to extract the features for the model?

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 6](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) of the [nltk book](https://www.nltk.org/book) has a great section on this exact problem (text classification using the gender identification example).

The most approach in this scenario is to use the tweet as a single string as the only feature. Here's an example using a naive bayes classifier:

```
import random

import nltk
import pandas as pd

# input data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['33324','24442','3956'],
    'gender':['female','male','male'],
    'tweets':[['hello','trump','today'],['blue','eyes','brown','hair'],['playstation','june']]
})

# featurize data to input into classifier
features = []
for tweet, gender in zip(df["tweets"], df["gender"]):
    features.append(({"feature": " ".join(tweet)}, gender))

# shuffle features
random.shuffle(features)    

# train test split, obvs use different split values for the real set or use sklearns train_test_split function
train_set, test_set = features[:2], features[2:]

# train
clf = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

# test
print(nltk.classify.accuracy(clf, test_set))
```

The nltk book has a ton more info on strategies that you can use to extract more informative features than what I've done above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was actually reading the example of chapter 6 before posting my question. But I was and still confused on how to approach this. Your reply  has helped but I think the test data set should contain only id number or tweets. As the model is expected to predict/return the gender.

Comment: @leena I think you're confused between test data and predict data. Test data is just a subset of the data that is labeled. Predict data doesn't having any labels, hence you want to use the classifier to make the predictions. For any machine learning/classification task, you should ALWAYS have a train set AND a test set before you start making predictions. The purpose of the test is data is to determine the performance of the model. Otherwise you can't know how well it will do when looking at future predictions in which we don't have the gender data.

Comment: Thank you Jay. I will do more reading on the subject. I appreciate your help.

Comment: can I apply the model on a `df_new` dataframe that consists of the tweets to get back to predicted gender? such as `df_new['gender'] = df_new.apply(lambda row: clf.classify(row), axis = 1) `

Comment: While the example is showing 100% accuracy, it is completely wrong. The text of a tweet cannot be used as a meaningful feature — most of the tweets are unique. This classifier has no way to judge the similarity of text strings. The example shown will always predict the same gender unless it is given an example from the training set.